# Java public classes with private dependent classes

Tags: java

One thing that has always bothered me in Java is:

How do you create a single public class that should be used by downstream consumers but then nicely organize the classes it depends on in packages?

For example (somewhat contrived), I have a class UserDao that relies on LdapPersistenceHelper and DBPersistenceHelper. The UserDao class is sitting in a package called com.company.dao and i would like the two helpers to live in a package called com.company.dao.persistencehelper. However, I do not want to make the two helpers generic enough that they could be used by others. How do I that? If I make the helpers "protected" (really, no modifier) then I can't reach them from the UserDao. If I make them public, someone else might use them.

Answer (score 6):

The root problem is that you're trying to use packages to "organize things nicely."  When Java packages were created, there were two design goals: (1) globally unique class naming, and (2) facilitating use of the protected/default access modifier.

The fact that you are constrained to having a folder structure of source that matches the packages inevitably leads to trying to use them to create "pretty/organized folder structure."  But that's not what it was created for, and as a consequence, it doesn't work very well with the access modifiers it was created to support.

Edit: As an aside, I am not passing judgement one way or the other.  I realized my first sentence may have sounded critical.  Lots of projects legitimately choose an organized and maintainable structure over trying to squeeze some extra bit of perceived value out of protected access.  Is it really that bad if the helper utility is public?  If you don't trust the other developers with access not to misuse it, can they be trusted not to just change the access modifiers too?

Comment: while strictly Bozho answers this question, I like this answer better because it appreciates the design problem

Comment: +1 this is by far the superior answer. If you are not prepared to make the helper classes adhere to a public interface or be a usable generic utility, they likely have no place in their own package. In fact, if they don't make sense outside of the context of a UserDao instance, they probably don't belong in their own class file.

Comment: @Tim: That patently untrue.  You may have an entire library of reusable code that you don't want to generally distribute for external use and therefore implicitly contract to providing future binary compatibility with them.

Comment: @Software Monkey, well, in such case it is better to document this package as internal as per Esko's answer. Sun has a lot of such classes in com.sun.* packages and I've heard of no one trying to actually use them.

Comment: @Sergey: I have encountered people using com.sun.* packages numerous times over the years, despite being warned against it.  This is a great example of my point, Java forces you to declare code as public when you don't want to commit to it's interface for use downstream (that is externally to your code) - now if Sun had obfuscated these packages in the JVM distribution then no-one would be using them.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to enforce this, unless you place the classes in the same package. No way to define sub-package visibility.

Comment: Got a question. If I use a library with a class without modifier so it can only be used in that package. And i create a package with the same name in my project. Can I use the class in the library in my own package this way?

Comment: Yes. But the language is designed to prevent accidents, not malfeasance. Stroustrup notes the same distinction for C++ in D&E.

Comment: yes, you can. Except if it is java.lang, lava.util, etc. :)

Comment: @Mark: Yes you can... unless the JAR in which the package was first found (in class-path/class-loader order) is sealed.  If it *is* sealed, then the class loader will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to put them in the same package as the public class, but with package access.

If you are using OSGi, you can leave implementation packages out of the set of exported packages.

Comment: interesting, I hadn't thought of using OSGI to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I would not worry about others using them. Just document them as internal packages, maybe even put them under a package "internal" or "impl". If somebody anyways uses them inappropriately, they can only harm and blame themselves (the only harm might be dealing with backward incompatible changes to those classes).

If you want stronger isolation, use OSGi.

Answer (score 1):

Note: One possible way around this (if you are distributing a JAR for others to use) is to use an obfuscater (I recommend [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)) to obfuscate the non-publicly consumable classes; again this does not prevent deliberate malfeasance, but it makes it pretty darn clear that there's no contract for downstream compatibility with those classes (and it makes it technically difficult to figure out how to use them).